# When should you decide to use a XMPP server or just WCF Services?

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, xmpp, comet

I have a project where we have decided to use a polling architecture through XMPP through to a WCF service.  The application is similar to a news feed system, where the logged-in client polls the service ever few seconds for an update in data (does not require streaming).

Initially I was considering using WebSockets and PUSH, however, since this is needing to be built on existing legacy technology, and most of the user's browsers will not support the newer WebSocket protocol, the decision was made to pursue this approach.

The number of concurrent clients will be relatively small - under 10,000.

If I'm using a WCF service to feed the clients, do I really need a XMPP/Comet server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd revisit push and consider using socket.io

http://socket.io/

Comment: I am looking at this a little closer again, and Socket.IO having fallback capabilities may be a good solution, however I'm not sure how much of a hit on the system page reloads are going to be, rather than keeping the socket open (posting new question).

Answer (score 0):

> If I'm using a WCF service to feed the clients, do I really need a XMPP/Comet server?

no, but it gives you much more power than WCF does with all its powerful extensions like Publish Subscribe and others. And its push not poll. You get the comet component for free with nearly every XMPP server. Its called BOSH in XMPP.

Alex